# Polymer template repeat with core ajax

Tags: polymer

Why cant i get the data from my json file to be printed between the `<p>` tags?

Am i missing something in the following code.
I am bit new to Polymer and its data binding concepts, so please help me.

my index.html file is,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Repeat</title>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
</head>
<style shim-shadowdom>
    html, body{
        margin: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        font-family: 'Roboto';
    }
</style>
<body unresolved>
    <polymer-element name="my-repeat">
    <template>
    <core-ajax auto url="http://localhost/repeat/data.json" handleAs="json" response="{{headerList.datas}}"></core-ajax>
        <style>
        </style>
        <template repeat="{{data in headerList.datas}}">
            <p>My name is </p>
            <p>{{data.name}}</p>
        </template>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer('my-repeat',{

    });
    </script>
    </polymer-element>

    <my-repeat></my-repeat>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my data.json file is,

```
{
    "datas":[
        {"name":"Sandeep"},
        {"name":"Surabhi"},
        {"name":"Sangeeta"},
        {"name":"Sumant"},
        {"name":"Rohan"},
        {"name":"Bapi"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in the binding core-ajax response.
It should be as this:

```
 <core-ajax auto 
    url="data.json" 
    handleAs="json" 
    response="{{headerList}}"></core-ajax>

    <template repeat="{{data in headerList.datas}}">
     ....
```

Here is the working example: [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hhduEb5OkoTtH8QjcQBx?p=preview)

Edit:

Here is the full example

```
<script src="//www.polymer-project.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">


<polymer-element name="my-repeat">
    <template>
    <core-ajax auto 
    url="data.json" 
    handleAs="json" 
    response="{{headerList}}"></core-ajax>
        <style>
        </style>
        Hi!

        {{headerList.datas[0].name}}
        <br><br>

        <template repeat="{{data in headerList.datas}}">
            <p>My name is </p>
            <p>{{data.name}}</p>
        </template>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer('my-repeat',{

      domReady: function(){


      },

    });
    </script>
    </polymer-element>

<my-repeat></my-repeat>
```

Comment: sorry but Plunk link does not load in my college due to some limitations. But what about the script part?

Comment: can <section></section> tags be repeated using template repeat. I am using core-pages having 3 sections, and am using selected attribute of core-pages to navigate throughout all three sections. So if i use template repeat i cannot navigate using selected attribute. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Sure you can use core-pages under template repeat, that is one of Polymer advantages. But you need to set the attributes correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tamplate without polymer-element. Just add is="auto-binding" attribute.

```
<template is="auto-binding">

    <core-ajax 
        auto
        url="data.json" 
        handleAs="json" 
        response="{{list}}">
    </core-ajax>

    <template repeat="{{list}}">
        <p>{{name}}</p>
    </template>

</template>
```